# I'm curious about link_to's ruby syntax

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I used it. The code below

```
<%= link_to user.nickname, conversations_path(user_id: user), remote: true, method: :post %>
```

I expressed user.nickname through the nickname method defined in db.
But the link_to syntax I know is 'name', url.
How can the first code be represented by user.nickname without ' '?
I want to change the text that appears in the first code, but user.nickname can not be changed to another because it is not represented in ' '.
How can I use it like the grammar I know?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Does that code work? If so, what is your question? If not, do you get any errors or unexpected output? What _is_ your desired output?

Comment: If you are curious about syntax the docs help alot e.g. [`ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelpers#link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First parameter to `link_to` is a string. It doesn't matter where the string comes from. It can come from user's object

```
link_to user.nickname, ...
```

or be a string literal

```
link_to "Joe", ...
```

> I want to change the text that appears in the first code

So just replace `user.nickname` with whatever you want to use there. But if you use a string literal, it'll be the same for all users.

If you want, say, to append a static string to all nicknames, you can use string concatenation.

```
link_to user.nickname + " (new)"
```

or string interpolation

```
link_to "#{user.nickname} (new)"
```

These different ways may very well look like arcane unintuitive spells to you now, but when the understanding of the difference between "a piece of syntax" and "a value it represents" clicks in your head, it'll become obvious.

Comment: How do I add text with user.nickname?

Comment: @김상열  You can use string interpolation, see the answer

Comment: @SebastiánMeza: added interpolation example _after_ that question :)